# Where to install icon for a user-specific application while adhering to FreeDesktop standards?

Tags: user-interface, gnome, kde-plasma, freedesktop.org, desktop-integration

I have a GUI application that I want to install per-user in a FreeDesktop-compliant manner. Reading the relevant specifications, it seem that a '.desktop' file should be placed in `~/.local/share/applications`, and that it should contain an `Icon` key set to the name of the icon without extensions.

The issue I'm facing is that I can't find per-user location where I should store the icon. The [Icon Theme specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/latest/ar01s07.html) state that application icons should at least be stored in `$prefix/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps`, but it never defines what values `$prefix` takes. It mentions `$HOME/.icons` but depricates it as legacy. All other paths I found were system-wide.

Gnome's [Integration Guide](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/icons.html.en) specifies that icons should be stored in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/` but makes no mention of per-user installation despite alluding to per-user installations elsewhere in the guide.

Given that what I managed to find does not provide me with the information I want, I ask this:

Where should a place my application's icon so that xdg desktops can find them?

Kindly note that I am aware of `kde4-config --path icon` and friends. I want to avoid handling icons for every desktop I want to support if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rereading the XDG Icon Specification, I noticed the specification references the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-0.7.html) by including  `$XDG_DATA_DIRS`. This inclusion implies that that the Base Directory Specification is also in effect, which in turn mandates that

> Lookups of the data file should search for ./subdir/filename relative to all base directories specified by $XDG_DATA_HOME and $XDG_DATA_DIRS . If an environment variable is either not set or empty, its default value as defined by this specification should be used instead. [(src)](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-0.7.html#referencing)

So, assuming my understanding is correct and XDG desktops adhere to specs, the user-specific icon location for your application is `$XDG_DATA_HOME/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/$YOURAPP.(png|xpm)` and `$XDG_DATA_HOME/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/$YOURAPP.svg`. File extensions are case-sensitive and only these three extensions are allowed. Also note that SVG support is optional.

If `$XDG_DATA_HOME` is not set, you should default to `$HOME/.local/share` as per the Base Directory Specification.